# Use opened file Javascript Windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm using JavaScript for app I'm currently working on. I've created file picker as shown in guide.

After file is picked I get object Windows.Storage.StorageFile. This file is image, my question is how to display image in img tag for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an image tag in your page like:

```
    <img id="theImage" />
```

then in your JavaScript callback from selecting the file, you'd set the img src property to a URL (using [createObjectURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453196.aspx)) that you create from the [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) reference:

```
    var picker = Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    picker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".png"]);
    picker.viewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.thumbnail;

    // Launch the picker in open mode
    picker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (file) {

        var imgElement = document.getElementById("theImage");
        imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file); 
    });
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing now is I cannot modify image because camanjs throws random exception. Can you help me out with this? I thing blob:url-to-link will not really help me

Comment: I'm not familiar with CamanJS, but from quick review of the doc would suspect the URL created with WinRT might not be something it could deal with... probably worth creating a new question with additional details on "random exception"